# JavaScript - confimation dialog - abort function

Tags: javascript, event-handling, abort

I found the following code on StackOverflow.
It is for an confimation dialog on an href-link.
It runs fine on my page, but if the user click on the "abort" Button, it reset the counter too.

I want that if the "abort" button is pressed no change will be done.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('reset_counter');
var confirmIt = function (e) {
    if (!confirm('Reset counter, sure?')) e.preventDefault();
};
for (var i = 0, l = elems.length; i < l; i++) {
    elems[i].addEventListener('click', confirmIt, false);
}
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: Does your abort button have a `reset_counter` class? If so, just remove it.

Comment: You can write `return;` without a return value to end a function early if that's what you want.  Your question isn't very clear considering the code does nothing.

Comment: Thanks for our answers! I'am not fine with JavaScript, so i only use it for this alert function. I don't know the placewhere i could put the "retrun;". I will try to explain it clearlier.